# Backspace, Tab not working in terminal (using ssh)

Tags: linux, debian, terminal

When I ssh into another machine with Debian with my account(with sudo permissions), my backspace key generates some awkward symbols on pressing. Also <kbd>Tab</kbd> & <kbd>del</kbd> keys don't work too.

On the other hand, I also have another account on the same machine & when I ssh through this account, its terminal works perfectly fine. I couldn't figure out why is this happening.

Answer (score 92):

Beside "stty" solution, you may try the "TERM" solution.

You ssh to your Debian from some terminal (putty, solaris dterm, debain xterm, you-name-it), this termninal announce capabilities (which includes keys such as Backspace and Tab) via TERM environment variable.

So, after ssh to unix host (it doesn't depend debian it or other host) set the TERM variable according to your terminal. Consider you're using bash as shell and vt100 as terminal:

```
export TERM=vt100
```

ps: TERM should be announced via ssh automagically, but in some circumstances this magic fails.

Comment: still doesn't work :(

Comment: What terminal are you using? And what the value of TERM you have tried?

Comment: I tried vt100. How do I get to know the value of TERM? I tried ssh from cygwin (in windows) to Debian. If there are problems with cygwin, I even tried it from ubuntu terminal, but same problem.

Comment: Not sure cygwin has good terminal emulation, as far as I know, cygwin just using regular windows console which lacks terminal emulation (may be wrong).
From ubuntu all should works just fine. Something wrong with shell or termcap library on debian. Login from Ubuntu and give me output of commands:
1. echo $TERM
2. stty -a

Comment: Well it works fine from my ubuntu machine, wonder why I hadn't verified it before.($TERM was 'xterm' there). So the problem is with cygwin only. Well anyways problem solved if it works with ubuntu :)

Comment: While this didn't directly help me, since TERM was correctly set, it did help identify the problem. I was missing the terminfo entries for my terminal. I am using urxvt and on arch you need to install rxvt-unicode-terminfo to fix this particular issue

Comment: I got this when connecting to a Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS on Hetzner. In my case the `TERM` was `alacritty` and changing it to `vt100` worked. On a different server on AWS I got a warning regarding the wrong `TERM`. Why does that happen? Does it depend on the ssh server?

Comment: Worked for me, I have suckless ST, but machine to which i SSH' into was plain bare fresh debian, checking "echo $TERM" on my machine it says `st-256color`. Trying to set it in debian results in error, but setting `vt100` as sugested here fixed backspace and tab.

Answer (score 63):

I have seen such problems before.

Take the backspace for example, the remote host expects some character to be used as "erase/backspace" , while you pressing backspace in the terminal , the terminal program will send some character to the remote host, if what the remote host expects diffs with the characters sent by the terminal program, you would encounter this issue. So a quick fix is as below:

1. run command `#stty -a` in the remote host, and find what is expected to be an erase code in the output. Say `erase=^?`.
2. In the terminal, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>v</kbd> and press your backspace. You'll see what code is sent as "erase". Say it is `^H`.
3. In the remote host, run `#stty erase ^H`.
   (Note: use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>v</kbd> + <kbd>Backspace</kbd>, do not type the ^ manually)

You can fix the Tab issue with the same as above.

Comment: My backspace character is some special symbol something like an inverted triangle. So its not working

Comment: This simple comment is certainly the best solution I have seen to this. It feels like a kludge but it works.

Comment: This worked for me! What I don't understand though is why my shell handles backspace as expected, but reading from stdin in my app does not. Doing your suggested change results in backspace working for both. My understanding is that the shell handles stdin buffering, so shouldn't the backspace-handling be the same for both the shell and an app?

Comment: What if no code at all is sent?  Ctrlv + backspace produces nothing...

Comment: For me, the backspace code is the same as `stty -a` output, but still does not work

Answer (score 28):

This is because your default shell is `sh`, to use `bash`, just run `bash` from your shell.

```
bash
```

To set `bash` as your default shell:

```
chsh -s /bin/bash
```

or

```
sudo chsh -s /bin/bash yourusername
```

Comment: This one fixed it for me. Never even though to look at my login shell!

Comment: I am seeing this problem, but my shell is bash.

Answer (score 8):

I usually use this to fix any funky character output in my terminal. It resets all the special characters to their default values.

```
stty sane
```

From the stty man page:

> same  as cread -ignbrk brkint -inlcr -igncr icrnl -iutf8 -ixoff -iuclc -ixany imaxbel opost -olcuc -ocrnl onlcr -onocr -onlret -ofill -ofdel nl0 cr0 tab0 bs0 vt0 ff0 isig icanon iexten echo echoe echok -echonl -noflsh -xcase -tostop -echoprt echoctl echoke, **all special characters to their default values**

Answer (score 7):

Your shell may be set to `/bin/sh` instead of `/bin/bash`

Comment: Related to this answer: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/50542/backspace-del-arrow-keys-not-working-with-interactive-programs-in-tilda

Comment: http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-set-bash-as-your-default-shell/

Comment: This would be more helpful if it explained a little more and how to change it, but it was the problem I had. Thanks @Tom for your link that fixed the issue for me.

Comment: This was the reason in my case.. for that particular user. No shell was defined in `/etc/passwd`, when I added `:/bin/bash` to his line it worked. You can find out what shell is being used with `echo $0`

Answer (score 5):

Verify that the remote host shell **TERM setting matches your terminal's** term setting (localhost) **and** that the remote host **supports the TERM setting**.

E.g.:

1. From iTerm (or another terminal app)

```bsh
$ echo $TERM
xterm-256color
```

> You don't need to open tmux. I am using tmux to force the error since it uses an relatively uncommon terminal config.

2. Open tmux (basically another terminal within a terminal app)

```bsh
$ echo $TERM
tmux-256color
```

3. From tmux run ssh command & check TERM setting

```bsh
$ ssh <remote host>
.
.
# Logged into remote host now run...
$ echo $TERM
tmux-256color
```

So tmux communicated to the remote host properly but we have backspace or some other matching key issue. Lets check which terminals the remote host supports.

4. From remote host

```bsh
$ toe -a
xterm-256color  xterm with 256 colors
xterm-color     generic "ANSI" color xterm (X Window System)
xterm           X11 terminal emulator
linux           linux console
dumb            80-column dumb tty
ansi            ansi/pc-term compatible with color
```

Looks like the remote host does not support `tmux-256color`, the TERM value sent by tmux. It does support `xterm-256color` which we know our terminal app supports.

5. From remote host change TERM value

```bsh
export TERM=xterm-256color
```

Comment: The question doesn't mention `tmux` so although the setting of `$TERM` might be the issue, fixing it in `tmux` probably isn't so useful

Comment: Your answer could be improved by explaining why your solution correctly would resolve it for the user in the question. Note that `tmux` is not mentioned by the user.

Answer (score 4):

on top of paul's answer, if you want to retain the ability to have colorful output, you can use xterm-88color

```
echo 'export TERM=xterm-88color' >> ~/.bashrc
source ~/.bashrc
```

Comment: `toe -a` shows a list of supported terminal types ... `xterm-88color` is by far not the only option and in fact may be unavailable on particular systems.

Comment: In my case, I had to switch from xterm-256color to xterm-88color and it is far better than other options.

Answer (score 1):

[I followed the advice in this old reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/tmux/comments/4vxpk7/comment/d66424s/?utm_source=reddit&utm_medium=web2x&context=3):

I copied the `.terminfo` folder from my user directory to the `.terminfo` folder under my root user directory. (I had the problem specifically when doing `su -i`)

For some reason the color terminal setting I was using was present under my regular user ie file called `.terminfo/x/xterm-24bit`, but not under the root user.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered a similar issue, that when `ssh` to a remote machine from `tmux`, my <kbd>Backspace</kbd> key starts to generate spaces instead. If this is your case, check in the tmux config for:

```
set -g default-terminal "screen-256color"
```

The above would set the environment variable `TERM` to "screen-256color", which would be used by the SSH client to communicate with the remote machine. After establishing the connection, the remote shell would contain the same `$TERM` value, while setting it to an unsupported value is one of the reason why <kbd>Backspace</kbd> stops working.

In my case, the remote machine doesn't support "screen-256color":

```bash
$ toe -a
xterm-xfree86   xterm terminal emulator (XFree86)
xterm-vt220     xterm emulating vt220
xterm-r6        xterm X11R6 version
xterm-r5        xterm R5 version
xterm-mono      monochrome xterm
xterm-color     generic color xterm
xterm-256color  xterm with 256 colors
xterm           xterm terminal emulator (X Window System)
wsvt25m         NetBSD wscons in 25 line DEC VT220 mode with Meta
vt100           dec vt100 (w/advanced video)
linux           linux console
```

so either modifying the tmux config or setting directly `export TERM="xterm-256color"` would solve the problem.

Comment: Your answer could be improved by explaining why your solution correctly would resolve it for the user in the question. Note that `tmux` is not mentioned by the user.

Comment: @roaima @Kusalananda Thanks for pointing it out that OP didn't mention `tmux`. I've modified my answer to not assume it's certainly a tmux issue and added more info on the relationship of SSH and `$TERM`.

Answer (score 0):

After connecting from Fedora to an OpenWrt host with ssh the remote bash
terminal had problems with some control characters. TERM variable in source
host was set to rxvt-unicode-256color. Since it seemed that OpenWrt repos did
not provide terminfo file for that terminal I copied rxvt-unicode-256color
terminfo file from source host to remote host directory:
`/usr/share/terminfo/r/` .
It worked.

Answer (score -1):

**Update**:

Thanks for pointing out the shortcomings of my previous answer.

The user's problem with the terminal in a remote machine and the problem I faced in a docker container may be caused by the same issue, which is related to the `terminfo` (about [terminfo](https://tldp.org/HOWTO/Text-Terminal-HOWTO-16.html)).

- The `USERA` account works well in that machine may set up `terminfo` correctly while another `USERB` account doesn't. So using `USERA`'s `terminfo` may fix this problem.

But, where is the `terminfo`?

- Here is what I found in a `ubuntu:20.04` docker container:

```bash
root@9a6c3b2bf6ea:/etc/terminfo# cat README
This directory is for system-local terminfo descriptions. By default,
ncurses will search ${HOME}/.terminfo first, then /etc/terminfo (this
directory), then /lib/terminfo, and last not least /usr/share/terminfo.
```

**Solution**:

1. Check the following locations and find the `terminfo` you need:

   - `${HOME}/.terminfo` (associated with **accounts**, check this one first)
   - `/etc/terminfo`
   - `/lib/terminfo`
   - `/usr/share/terminfo`
2. Copy the `terminfo` from `USERA` to `USERB`
3. Open a new session to refresh your terminal

---

**Original Answer**:

I encountered this problem when I tried to add `bash` and use it in a [distroless](https://github.com/GoogleContainerTools/distroless) image. (Even though this behavior is unsafe ...)

I build my application image with the [multi-stages build](https://docs.docker.com/build/building/multi-stage/).
I run:

```
docker run -it <my_image> bash
```

And I found that `<backspace>` doesn't work.

**Solution**:

In my Dockerfile:

```
COPY --from=builder /lib/terminfo /lib/terminfo
```

Comment: This answer is specific to running is a Docker container and will not help in the OP's environment.

Comment: Welcome to Unix & Linux! Your answer could be improved by explaining the issue, i.e., the underlying cause of the problem and why your solution correctly would resolve it for the user in the question. Note that Docker is not mentioned by the user.