# In SSH Terminal, I can't type any character. All character is changed strrange character

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssh, terminal, ssh-tunneling

I'm sorry for my poor English.

My PC OS is Windows 7.

When I ssh Ubuntu 18.04 remote server (through gateway server), all characters I type are changed by a strange character: `^@` is appended after every character.

For example, I type `yes`, then there is `y^@e^@s^@` in console.

Also, when I hit backspace key to remove character, it doesn't work. `^H` show up in console.

I'm very confused this strange situation. I found the following posts:

[Backspace, Tab not working in terminal (using ssh)](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/43103/backspace-tab-not-working-in-terminal-using-ssh)

https://superuser.com/questions/641095/bash-how-to-globally-fix-h-and-backspace-problems

But neither helped me.

How do I fix the problem? Where do I check? local config file? remote server? gateway server?

Thank you.

*EDIT:*
I use PyCharm SSH Terminal.

Comment: It looks like the SSH client's terminal on Windows sends input as UTF-16, check the settings and set it to UTF-8. Please add to your question which client/terminal you are using.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "through gateway server". Are you connecting first with ssh to a "gateway server", and then making a connection from the gateway server to the Ubuntu server? The "^@" is one way that the NUL character ('\0' in C) is shown. Typing `stty erase ` and then pressing the backspace key might help a bit but getting rid of the NUL characters is your first priority.